# awkで正規表現のキャプチャの利用方法

Tags: 正規表現, awk

ファル名 keisan.csv
2018年月21日,abc,\387
2018年6月23日,abc,"\1,418"
2018年6月23日,abc,\276
2018年6月30日,abc,\925
2018年6月30日,abc,\619

awkで３番目のファイールドだけを下記などで、
　　　　sum += $3
計算したいのでが、取得したcsvファイルが３桁カンマや円マークが
入っているため計算できません。

正規表現で桁数カンマと、ダブルクオーテーション、円マークを
取り除いたのですが、awkの正規表現でも同じようなことは可能でしょうか

"?\(\d+),?(\d+)"?
　　　　$1$2

最終的に、３番目のフィールドだけを計算したいのですが、
awkではmatchを使うという記事を参考に書きを試して
みましたが、うまくいきません。

awk -F, 'match($0, /"?\(\d+),?(\d+)"?/, a) {print a[1]}' keisan.csv

Comment: GNU awk の `FPAT(Field PATtern)`変数を使うと `gawk -vFPAT='"[^"]*"|[^,]*' '{gsub("[^0-9]","",$3);sum+=$3}END{print sum}' keisan.csv` な感じでしょうかね。

Comment: こちらでうまくいきました。"[^0-9]"で簡単に数値のみ残せますね。勉強になりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

質問の例にあるのはGNU awk固有の書き方ですね。コマンド名をgawkとすると、こんな感じかと。

```
$ gawk -F, 'match($3, /"?([0-9]+)"?/, a) { print a[1] }' keisan.csv
```

一般的なawkだとこんな感じでしょうか。

```
$ awk -F, 'match($3, /[0-9]+/) { print substr($3, RSTART, RLENGTH) }' < keisan.csv
```

Comment: $ gawk -F, 'match($3, /"?([0-9]+)"?/, a) { print a[1] }' keisan.csv

Comment: $ gawk -F, 'match($3, /"?([0-9]+)"?/, a) { print a[1] }' keisan.csv　を実行すると、1,418が、1と表示されて、カンマ（,)以降の418が取得されないようです。

Comment: なるほど、数値のカンマがあるからカンマでフィールドを区切ってはまずかったですね。metropolisさんのようにFPATを使うか、質問例のように$0を使って`gawk 'match($0, /\\([0-9,]+)"?$/, a) { print a[1] }' keisan.csv`とかになりますね。